# How to prove that Julia set are uncountable?

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals

This is an exercise from Falconer's book. How can I prove that Julia set $J(f_c)$ is uncountable for all c, $f_c(z) = z^2 +c$？It gives me a hint that perfect set E is uncountable, so I want to prove $J(f_c)$ is a perfect set. But I only know that $J(f_c)$ is closed.

Another solution I tried is to choose a point $z_0$ in the filled-in Julia set K and a circle $C$ outside K and find a boundary point on the line joining $z_0$ and $z \in C$. Is this method feasible?

I'll be very grateful for any help.

Comment: **Theorem**
Let $R$ be a rational map of degree at least two. $\mathcal{J}$ is a perfect set and either $\mathcal{J} = \mathbb{C}_\infty$ or $J$ has an empty interior.

Comment: How can I prove this Julia set is perfect? I'm still stuck here.

Comment: Sorry, I think I have found this proposition(14.9) in the book Fractal Geometry of Falconer, which I missed before.